# Adding Image on the maintance page 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, maintenance

I just created a a new "theme" for my maintaince mode by copy and rename the defult folder under /pub/error/ and renamed local.sample.xml to local.xml.

In the 503.pthml file under the "mytheme" folder i created I'm trying to add a picture:
[image]

How ever when i load the maintenace page the picture is broken. anyone who knows why? is there anything do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the same path as the path to the image you included in your post, I'm going to guess it's because you placed the image under `pub/error/` or a subfolder like `pub/error/images`; however, you're referencing the path `/images/logo.gif`. You need to adjust the path to use the `/pub/error/images` path (or just `/error/images` if your docroot is set up correctly).